# Deleting from dict if found in new list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, list

Say I have a dictionary with whatever number of values.
And then I create a list.
If any of the values of the list are found in the dictionary, regardless of whether or not it is a key or an index how do I delete the full value?

E.g:

```
dictionary = {1:3,4:5}
list = [1]
...
    dictionary = {4:5}
```

How do I do this without creating a new dictionary?

Comment: Do you mean regardless of whether or not it is a key or a value? So in you example if you had list = [3] would you expect the same result?

Answer (score 7):

```
for key, value in list(dic.items()):
    if key in lst or value in lst:
        del dic[key]
```

No need to create a separate list or dictionary.

I interpreted "whether or not it is a key or an index" to mean "whether or not it is a key or a value [in the dictionary]"

Comment: I think this breaks in Python 3, where `dict.items()` returns a generator.  Best to do `for k, v in list(d.items())` in that case.

Answer (score 4):

it's a bit complicated because of your "values" requirement:

```
>>> dic = {1: 3, 4: 5}
>>> ls = set([1])
>>> dels = []
>>> for k, v in dic.items():
    if k in ls or v in ls:
        dels.append(k)

>>> for i in dels:
    del dic[i]

>>> dic
{4: 5}
```

Comment: We seem to have interpreted the question in different ways - he was referring to values in the list, and keys/indices in the dictionary. I think he wants to remove all key-value pairs in the dictionary where the key is in the list.

Comment: Why create the extra "dels" list? Why not just delete the item directly?

Comment: because I'm iterating over dict, and such deletion would raise a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: @Dominic: there is no such thing as index in dict, the only sensible way I can interpret the question is to assume that OP means keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

A one liner to do this would be :

```
[dictionary.pop(x) for x in list if x in dictionary.keys()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {1:3,4:5}
list = [1]

for key in list:
  if key in dictionary:
     del dictionary[key]
```

Comment: This would only delete entries that have 1 as a key. The question also called for deleting entries where the values matched 1.

Comment: @twneale - in my view, the question is ambiguous - the question asks to delete "keys or indexes" in the dictionary for all values in the list. Some people have interpreted a dictionary index to mean the value, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dictionary = {1:3,4:5}
>>> list = [1]
>>> for x in list:
...     if x in dictionary:
...             del(dictionary[x])
... 
>>> dictionary
{4: 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def remKeys(dictionary, list):
    for i in list:
        if i in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary.pop(i)
    return dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
for i in list:
    if dictionary.has_key(i):
         del dictionary[i]
```

But I am sure there are better ways.

Comment: `del` is correct (there's no keyword `delete`!-) but `has_key` is useless (**much** better: `if i in dictionary:`).

Comment: it was referred to my setting to None. I misunderstood the OP wanted to set it to none.

Answer (score 0):

A few more testcases to define how I interpret your question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def test(beforedic,afterdic,removelist):
    d = beforedic
    l = removelist
    for i in l:
        for (k,v) in list(d.items()):
            if k == i or v == i:
                del d[k]

    assert d == afterdic,"d is "+str(d)

test({1:3,4:5},{4:5},[1])
test({1:3,4:5},{4:5},[3])
test({1:3,4:5},{1:3,4:5},[9])
test({1:3,4:5},{4:5},[1,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary is small enough, it's easier to just make a new one.  Removing all items whose key is in the set `s` from the dictionary `d`:

```
d = dict((k, v) for (k, v) in d.items() if not k in s)
```

Removing all items whose key or value is in the set `s` from the dictionary `d`:

```
d = dict((k, v) for (k, v) in d.items() if not k in s and not v in s)
```